# Python: Extracting excel cell values based on value in 1st column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have certain csv  files, which I am reading into python using glob2 and pandas. I need to extract values from column C below, only when column b reads 'Refrigerant outlet temperature [K]'

I have tried `iloc` and `ix` etc but it does not seem to work. Any help will be appreciated!

### Data

- `Run-No-73-2020-06-19-tubes.csv`

```py
XY plot,Circuit1
Xdata,Tube Nos [-],1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0
Xdata,Tube location [m],1.2192,2.4384,3.6576000000000004,4.8768,6.096,7.315200000000001,8.5344,9.7536,10.972800000000001,12.192,13.411200000000001,14.630400000000002
Ydata,Air Capacity [kW],128.65744079750252,557.5987436634471,611.6895245310138,867.1120934400609,880.6472263147532,646.1566629786406,353.37764226275385,701.1936628735328,277.16751076817246,108.71807383715976,63.93367637039801,48.20221501922388
Ydata,Refrigerant Capacity [kW],128.65744079750252,557.5987436634471,611.6895245310138,867.1120934400609,880.6472263147532,646.1566629786406,353.37764226275385,701.1936628735328,277.16751076817246,108.71807383715976,63.93367637039801,48.20221501922388
Ydata,Air inlet temperature [K],287.73443752665037,293.62898912497667,294.66152516549255,299.83,299.83,294.60231536327103,288.2535559573605,294.22475761072315,295.2360530869296,298.1351411379294,298.6581266925062,299.83
Ydata,Air outlet temperatre [K],285.32708407870246,287.0379660930306,287.42797830233997,289.49305040425156,289.37463082731745,287.0732716330538,284.26217089773894,286.65395928135194,290.452205072322,296.02210052208505,297.41128036299074,298.88573491490536
Ydata,Refrigerant inlet temperature [K],282.06866544516015,282.0408618731072,281.9684299160883,281.8358732724386,281.6523179628393,281.4372847400658,281.22161110938123,281.01919243469075,280.9596172656558,293.30146583088845,295.8248282516778,297.69635994028135
Ydata,Refrigerant outlet temperature [K],282.06977093355556,282.0444935822205,281.9831062264791,281.86312735576183,281.6982117574008,281.50315761520966,281.30284155488374,281.10905867497513,280.95805961068584,289.0699342169462,293.25764285917217,295.73050574117156
Ydata,Quality [-],0.03820153700913367,0.1530250152778651,0.27882672076711923,0.4571868288046692,0.6382423040304033,0.7711267397869899,0.8439261406082131,0.987421761736249,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
Ydata,StraightTube LiquidMass[kg],0.05200262747897293,0.02983742443485275,0.01807118982849003,0.011767572460956995,0.007626647877668588,0.005049182823989872,0.0035370092417716767,0.0018508212670238656,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
Ydata,StraightTube VaporMass[kg],0.0009532204387557756,0.0017475498837913807,0.002164836745766585,0.0023807604093886428,0.0025140130683821574,0.0025880160293021105,0.002623542541899748,0.0026655145389588163,0.008526537791069882,0.0025540256998253467,0.002470880850567846,0.0024191244047201727

XY plot,Circuit2
Xdata,Tube Nos [-],1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0
Xdata,Tube location [m],1.2192,2.4384,3.6576000000000004,4.8768,6.096,7.315200000000001,8.5344,9.7536,10.972800000000001,12.192,13.411200000000001,14.630400000000002
Ydata,Air Capacity [kW],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,Refrigerant Capacity [kW],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,Air inlet temperature [K],293.43398301796174,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,289.4338405287636,288.430909330496,286.34653983246506,288.73781639103476,293.1717652193233,299.2440633462531,299.83
Ydata,Air outlet temperatre [K],293.43398301796174,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,289.4338405287636,288.430909330496,286.34653983246506,288.73781639103476,293.1717652193233,299.2440633462531,299.83
Ydata,Refrigerant inlet temperature [K],293.43398301796174,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,289.4338405287636,288.430909330496,286.34653983246506,288.73781639103476,293.1717652193233,299.2440633462531,299.83
Ydata,Refrigerant outlet temperature [K],293.43398301796174,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,289.4338405287636,288.430909330496,286.34653983246506,288.73781639103476,293.1717652193233,299.2440633462531,299.83
Ydata,Quality [-],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,StraightTube LiquidMass[kg],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,StraightTube VaporMass[kg],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

XY plot,Circuit3
Xdata,Tube Nos [-],1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0
Xdata,Tube location [m],1.2192,2.4384,3.6576000000000004,4.8768,6.096,7.315200000000001,8.5344,9.7536,10.972800000000001,12.192,13.411200000000001,14.630400000000002
Ydata,Air Capacity [kW],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,Refrigerant Capacity [kW],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,Air inlet temperature [K],287.88204114582396,289.91141130063556,294.61453876921416,299.83,299.83,299.2938853081713,294.28056073119944,297.0515077217529,299.2503110085603,298.670284733177,299.83,299.83
Ydata,Air outlet temperatre [K],287.88204114582396,289.91141130063556,294.61453876921416,299.83,299.83,299.2938853081713,294.28056073119944,297.0515077217529,299.2503110085603,298.670284733177,299.83,299.83
Ydata,Refrigerant inlet temperature [K],287.88204114582396,289.91141130063556,294.61453876921416,299.83,299.83,299.2938853081713,294.28056073119944,297.0515077217529,299.2503110085603,298.670284733177,299.83,299.83
Ydata,Refrigerant outlet temperature [K],287.88204114582396,289.91141130063556,294.61453876921416,299.83,299.83,299.2938853081713,294.28056073119944,297.0515077217529,299.2503110085603,298.670284733177,299.83,299.83
Ydata,Quality [-],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,StraightTube LiquidMass[kg],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,StraightTube VaporMass[kg],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

XY plot,Circuit4
Xdata,Tube Nos [-],1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0
Xdata,Tube location [m],1.2192,2.4384,3.6576000000000004,4.8768,6.096,7.315200000000001,8.5344,9.7536,10.972800000000001,12.192,13.411200000000001,14.630400000000002
Ydata,Air Capacity [kW],324.2858791148862,187.56138792652828,362.28690540388317,866.2567716068745,877.8584726868849,892.8778669932161,529.1404732816158,453.0391619907644,445.1486125659339,152.94340369686785,91.351868914147,54.75146756270347
Ydata,Refrigerant Capacity [kW],324.2858791148862,187.56138792652828,362.28690540388317,866.2567716068745,877.8584726868849,892.8778669932161,529.1404732816158,453.0391619907644,445.1486125659339,152.94340369686785,91.351868914147,54.75146756270347
Ydata,Air inlet temperature [K],288.1590828162914,289.93677040476643,289.44979570175497,299.83,299.83,299.83,291.9408286275717,290.06672195234455,294.8565822186613,298.4022861008676,299.2938853081713,299.83
Ydata,Air outlet temperatre [K],284.72202741861884,286.4067569809361,285.2082843351167,289.5005139766707,289.3990777584913,289.2671190010668,285.85267368305824,284.93673749615846,288.93271151332686,295.4318816600308,297.510368265675,298.7576981570571
Ydata,Refrigerant inlet temperature [K],282.06866544516015,282.02719198728965,281.95266879081737,281.84745046825657,281.6901914446278,281.4858829984123,281.26770038005645,281.0618771179481,280.99028255144793,291.5825839488892,295.23570317716934,297.40536251483957
Ydata,Refrigerant outlet temperature [K],282.06977093355556,282.0346477254171,281.9638739596611,281.8659820183775,281.7268495400302,281.5419285349685,281.3445718679992,281.1516326061901,280.9821724860505,285.8001355080917,291.60532576075934,295.1784876660862
Ydata,Quality [-],0.07836040599914024,0.11725185759585831,0.19202327568607663,0.3701633340183372,0.5506124758982709,0.7340122710481893,0.84277708195303,0.9357333979727313,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
Ydata,StraightTube LiquidMass[kg],0.04238172211675523,0.029472194212287403,0.022564133919384152,0.014807407051891949,0.00939233515603143,0.006008494836946007,0.0038170624296599296,0.002292504024124635,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
Ydata,StraightTube VaporMass[kg],0.0012986096426605906,0.0017599550523208114,0.002003169989855606,0.002273304655373232,0.002454386659648168,0.002558149670659315,0.0026174966483184167,0.0026537478458813412,0.003954875962265497,0.0026113531381152925,0.0024961462401893787,0.0024264644023461934

XY plot,Circuit5
Xdata,Tube Nos [-],1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0
Xdata,Tube location [m],1.2192,2.4384,3.6576000000000004,4.8768,6.096,7.315200000000001,8.5344,9.7536,10.972800000000001,12.192,13.411200000000001,14.630400000000002
Ydata,Air Capacity [kW],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,Refrigerant Capacity [kW],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,Air inlet temperature [K],299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,298.5388137812701,291.82719189861336,297.2476283681938,294.66525693254084,299.83
Ydata,Air outlet temperatre [K],299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,298.5388137812701,291.82719189861336,297.2476283681938,294.66525693254084,299.83
Ydata,Refrigerant inlet temperature [K],299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,298.5388137812701,291.82719189861336,297.2476283681938,294.66525693254084,299.83
Ydata,Refrigerant outlet temperature [K],299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,298.5388137812701,291.82719189861336,297.2476283681938,294.66525693254084,299.83
Ydata,Quality [-],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,StraightTube LiquidMass[kg],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,StraightTube VaporMass[kg],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

XY plot,Circuit6
Xdata,Tube Nos [-],1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0
Xdata,Tube location [m],1.2192,2.4384,3.6576000000000004,4.8768,6.096,7.315200000000001,8.5344,9.7536,10.972800000000001,12.192,13.411200000000001,14.630400000000002
Ydata,Air Capacity [kW],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,Refrigerant Capacity [kW],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,Air inlet temperature [K],299.27111679864606,298.7099228896796,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83
Ydata,Air outlet temperatre [K],299.27111679864606,298.7099228896796,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83
Ydata,Refrigerant inlet temperature [K],299.27111679864606,298.7099228896796,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83
Ydata,Refrigerant outlet temperature [K],299.27111679864606,298.7099228896796,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83
Ydata,Quality [-],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,StraightTube LiquidMass[kg],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,StraightTube VaporMass[kg],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

XY plot,Circuit7
Xdata,Tube Nos [-],1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0
Xdata,Tube location [m],1.2192,2.4384,3.6576000000000004,4.8768,6.096,7.315200000000001,8.5344,9.7536,10.972800000000001,12.192,13.411200000000001,14.630400000000002
Ydata,Air Capacity [kW],128.65744079750252,557.5987436634471,611.6895245310138,867.1120934400609,880.6472263147532,646.1566629786406,353.37764226275385,706.0813868942156,200.2466168775888,147.88949624482066,88.27912430075331,52.93883092776015
Ydata,Refrigerant Capacity [kW],128.65744079750252,557.5987436634471,611.6895245310138,867.1120934400609,880.6472263147532,646.1566629786406,353.37764226275385,706.0813868942156,200.2466168775888,147.88949624482066,88.27912430075331,52.93883092776015
Ydata,Air inlet temperature [K],287.73443752665037,293.62898912497667,294.66152516549255,299.83,299.83,294.60231536327103,288.2535559573605,294.3878975591642,297.14701644377396,298.45132413428803,299.31189707690294,299.83
Ydata,Air outlet temperatre [K],285.32708407870246,287.0379660930306,287.42797830233997,289.49305040425156,289.37463082731745,287.0732716330538,284.26217089773894,286.7219448049956,293.2809052230303,295.5780709957955,297.58807197867196,298.7931286681128
Ydata,Refrigerant inlet temperature [K],282.06866544516015,282.0408618731072,281.9684299160883,281.8358732724386,281.6523179628393,281.4372847400658,281.22161110938123,281.01919243469075,288.16469237130696,291.8576157769132,295.3910405496458,297.4858038206114
Ydata,Refrigerant outlet temperature [K],282.06977093355556,282.0444935822205,281.9831062264791,281.86312735576183,281.6982117574008,281.50315761520966,281.30284155488374,281.10905867497513,281.0434889052896,286.2349653756815,291.8727637443179,295.3290097795765
Ydata,Quality [-],0.03820153700913367,0.1530250152778651,0.27882672076711923,0.4571868288046692,0.6382423040304033,0.7711267397869899,0.8439261406082131,0.9884185099398954,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
Ydata,StraightTube LiquidMass[kg],0.05200262747897293,0.02983742443485275,0.01807118982849003,0.011767572460956995,0.007626647877668588,0.005049182823989872,0.0035370092417716767,0.0018421672256667635,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
Ydata,StraightTube VaporMass[kg],0.0009532204387557756,0.0017475498837913807,0.002164836745766585,0.0023807604093886428,0.0025140130683821574,0.0025880160293021105,0.002623542541899748,0.002665814059327943,0.0028050769807330656,0.0025957289487024676,0.002484614869749683,0.00241726455960469

XY plot,Circuit8
Xdata,Tube Nos [-],1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0
Xdata,Tube location [m],1.2192,2.4384,3.6576000000000004,4.8768,6.096,7.315200000000001,8.5344,9.7536,10.972800000000001,12.192,13.411200000000001,14.630400000000002
Ydata,Air Capacity [kW],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,Refrigerant Capacity [kW],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,Air inlet temperature [K],293.43398301796174,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,289.4338405287636,288.430909330496,286.34653983246506,288.7280832378127,293.1930369964496,299.31189707690294,299.83
Ydata,Air outlet temperatre [K],293.43398301796174,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,289.4338405287636,288.430909330496,286.34653983246506,288.7280832378127,293.1930369964496,299.31189707690294,299.83
Ydata,Refrigerant inlet temperature [K],293.43398301796174,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,289.4338405287636,288.430909330496,286.34653983246506,288.7280832378127,293.1930369964496,299.31189707690294,299.83
Ydata,Refrigerant outlet temperature [K],293.43398301796174,299.83,299.83,299.83,299.83,289.4338405287636,288.430909330496,286.34653983246506,288.7280832378127,293.1930369964496,299.31189707690294,299.83
Ydata,Quality [-],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,StraightTube LiquidMass[kg],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ydata,StraightTube VaporMass[kg],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as text**. If relevant, plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

First I would check to make sure your csv loads properly. Change 'C:\Users\path\to\csv.csv' with the full file path to your file 'C:\Users\path\to' and the name of your file 'csv.csv':

```
import pandas as pd
pdDf = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\path\to\csv.csv')
print(pdDf.head(3))
```

It seems that you'll have trouble and need to add headers on your first row, and delete the blank rows in your csv. You might also try avoiding having any blank cells if possible, so replacing all blank cells in the middle of your table with 0's might help.

Say you keep "Circuit1" as your header in cell B1 and add "Temp1" as a header in cell C1. Then, you would simply add:

```
filteredDf = pdDf[pdDf['Circuit1']=='Refrigerant outlet temperature [K]']
refOutTemp = filteredDf[['Circuit1','Temp1']]
print(refOutTemp.head(3))
```

Then Save it to a csv with a different name...

```
refOutTemp.to_csv(r'C:\Users\path\to\Newcsv.csv', index = False, header=True)
```